# Arranging two side-by-side items in a Table View cell

Tags: ios, layout

Each row in a table (`UITableView`) consists of two elements: `label` and `value`.

*Value* is right-aligned and is wide enough to hold the text without wrapping.  *`Label`* is left aligned and takes **all** the width remaining after *value* (with a small margin). It allows text wrapping.

`UIStackView` (horizontal) appears to be the one, but I couldn't find a way to say: 'this takes as much as needed, and that takes all the rest'.

Is there a solution *without coding* ?

---

Update. After suggestion by Mr Bista, I've made the following:

StackView:
   Alignment: Fill
   Distribution: Fill
   Content Mode: Scale to Fill
   Constraints: leading: leadingMargin, trailing: trailingMargin

Label:
  Alignment: Left,
  Line Break: Word Wrap,
  Lines: 0
  Content Hugging Priority: 251 Both
  Content Compression Resistance Priority 750 Both

Value:
  Alignment: Right,
  Line Break: Truncate Tail,
  Lines: 1
  Content Hugging Priority: 251 Both
  Content Compression Resistance Priority
       751 Horizontal, 750 Vertical

The fields are spaced equally both with distribution *Fill* or *Fill Equally* (top image). With "Fill Proportionally" I lose Value at all (bottom image). Maybe, I am missing something?

[image: Distribution = Fill]

[image: Distribution = FillProportionally]

Answer (score 0):

Set the *Content Compression Resistance Priority* of `value` label to `751` i.e 1 more than `Label` Label `750`.

Also set the *Alignment* and *Distribution* of Stack View to *Fill*.